# JVector Map disable dragging/movement on touch devices

Tags: jquery, draggable

I used JVectorMap (http://jvectormap.com/maps/world/europe/) to create a map of europe. But I don't want that you can drag or move the map.

The map is based on jQuery. I get it for desktop computers but on touch devices I can drag and move the map. How can I disable this drag/move for this map?

Please, who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a late answer, but you can disable the zoom feature by setting the `panOnDrag: false` and `zoomOnScroll: false`.

I just haven't found how to disable the touch for mobile. I will update if found a way to do that.